# AngularJS: Display JSON data within <pre> only during development?

Tags: angularjs

I'm developing an AngularJS application, in which I'm displaying my JSON data on the screen using the `<pre> { "id": "108", "name": "My Data" } </pre>` tag for my development purpose.

Also, the application has many pages. Is it possible to show this `<pre>` tag only during the development and should not get displayed in release.

It's like similar to `DEBUG` and `RELEASE` mode in .NET.

What I have done till now is like having a constant at the rootscope of my application and inject as a dependency to my controller

```
 module.constant("DevMode", { display: true });
```

and at the HTML file, I check if the display value as true if it a DEV mode

```
 <div ng-if="editor.devMode.display==true">
     <pre>{{editor.data | json}}</pre>        
 </div>
```

Is this a fine approach? Need your suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: Just an idea: you could create your own debug directive `<my-debug></my-debug>` and then manage all inside the directive like loading the contents if the device mode is set

Answer (score 1):

I make a directive for that who use a global variable to show or not the debug :

```
directives.directive("dir.log", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: false,
        scope: {
            dlog: '=',
            dtitle: '@'
        },
        plain: true,
        controller: function ($scope, $rootScope) {
            $scope.logshow = false;
        },
        template: '<div ng-if="$root.debug" class="text-left">' +
        '<button tooltip-placement="right" uib-tooltip="log debug {{dtitle}}" ng-hide="logshow" ng-click="logshow=true;" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></button>' +
        '<button tooltip-placement="right" uib-tooltip="log debug {{dtitle}}" ng-hide="!logshow" ng-click="logshow=false;" class="btn btn-default btn-xs ng-hide" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>' +
        '</button>' +
        '<pre ng-if="logshow"><span ng-show="dtitle!=null">{{dtitle}}:<br></span>{{dlog |json}}</pre></div>'
    }
});
```

$root.debug is a boolean define in my rootscope.js

```
interfaceApp.run(function ($rootScope) {
       $rootScope.debug = true ; //debug mode
       ...
}
```

You need to inject $rootScope in your controllers

usage to show $scope.variableXX

```
<dir.log dlog="variableXX" dtitle="the variable XX"></dir.log>
```

it display a little arrow to show/unhide the log

dlog is the varialbe to log ( can be array or object )
dtitle is the used to show string on arrow hover.

hope it help, tell me if you use it and work.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good idea to leave some "debugging" code for production. Even if you add `ng-if`s or some custom directives, they will be calculated in every digest cycle which is not a good idea.

I see two options here.

Firstly, you can remove the debugging code with some tool - depending on what you are using to build your app. For example, if you would use gulp, then you could use [gulp-processhtml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-processhtml) to remove those debug previews for production release with:

```
<!-- build:remove -->
<pre>{{editor.data | json}}</pre> 
<!-- /build -->
```

Secondly, you can use some browser extensions that allow to inspect `$scope` values without messing up and dumping them in view. [Angular Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk) is definitely worth trying.